# PL/SQL Continue exection after error handled

Tags: oracle, loops, exception, plsql, oracle12c

I'm newbie with PL/SQL and i've got the following situation.

In the following scritp i want that the script continue iterating if they found any exception. The exception are handled but I cannot execute the continue statement out of a loop.

```
declare
  l_max_ID number;
  l_Temp_val number;
  type array_t is varray(135) of varchar2(30);
  arrayTable array_t := array_t('YSXQTAAA', 'YSXQTAFA', ... );
  array array_t := array_t('YSXQNAAA', 'YSXQNAFA', ...);
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(arrayTable.count);

    for i in 1..arrayTable.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Tabla impactada ' || arrayTable(i));
        execute immediate 'select max(id)+1 from ' || arrayTable(i) into l_max_ID;
        execute immediate 'alter sequence ' || array(i) || ' restart start with ' || TO_CHAR(l_Max_ID);
        dbms_output.put_line('alter sequence RS1.' || array(i) || ' restart start with ' || TO_CHAR(l_Max_ID));
    end loop;

  rollback;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        /* HAndle an error that gets raised when a query returns nothing */
        dbms_output.put_line('Error 1');

    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        /* HAndle the situation when too much data is returned such as with a select-into */
        dbms_output.put_line('Error 2');

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Error 3');
end;
```

The problem is that some tables doesn't have id column and the select throw an exception. The array contains more than a hundred elements and delete each one takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the exception handling block inside the loop:

```
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(arrayTable.count);

    for i in 1..arrayTable.count loop
        begin
            dbms_output.put_line('Tabla impactada ' || arrayTable(i));
            execute immediate 'select max(id)+1 from ' || arrayTable(i) into l_max_ID;
            execute immediate 'alter sequence ' || array(i) || ' restart start with ' || TO_CHAR(l_Max_ID);
            dbms_output.put_line('alter sequence RS1.' || array(i) || ' restart start with ' || TO_CHAR(l_Max_ID));
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                /* HAndle an error that gets raised when a query returns nothing */
                dbms_output.put_line('Error 1');
                continue;

            WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
                /* HAndle the situation when too much data is returned such as with a select-into */
                dbms_output.put_line('Error 2');
                continue;

            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('Error 3');
                continue;
        end;
    end loop;

  rollback;
end;
```